# Error Setting up websphere local development server

Tags: server, websphere, jython, websphere-8

Have installed the websphere 8.5.5 for developers and also websphere eclipse development tools. setup a new server in eclipse with websphere and also built a new profile. 
The server starts fine the and when i want to set it up via a jython script (Administration > Run administrative script ...) i get the following error.
Does anyone know what the problem might be:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic whitespace in path name, like "Program Files" problem, try installing to a directory with no spaces.